# Does TypeScript allow type aliases?

Tags: typescript, alias

So I wish I could use an alias to an ugly type that looks like this:

```
Maybe<Promise<Paged<Carrier>, Problem>>[]
```

Something like:

```
import Response = Maybe<Promise<Paged<Carrier>, Problem>>[];
```

Is there a way to do type aliases in TypeScript?

Comment: As ryan answered. One thing missing though is operator overloading, so you cannot extend something like number

Comment: 3 days ago typescript introduced type aliases: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases

Answer (score 147):

From version 1.4 Typescript supports type aliases ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx)).

> **Type Aliases**
>
> You can now define an alias for a type using the type keyword:
>
> ```
> type PrimitiveArray = Array<string|number|boolean>;
> type MyNumber = number;
> type NgScope = ng.IScope;
> type Callback = () => void;
> ```
>
> Type aliases are exactly the same as their original types; they are simply alternative names.

And from version 1.6 Typescript supports generic type aliases ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx)).

> **Generic type aliases**
>
> Leading up to TypeScript 1.6, type aliases were restricted to being simple aliases that shortened long type names.  Unfortunately, without being able to make these generic, they had limited use.  We now allow type aliases to be generic, giving them full expressive capability.
>
> ```
> type switcharoo<T, U> = (u: U, t:T)=>T;
> var f: switcharoo<number, string>;
> f("bob", 4);
> ```

Comment: Type aliases in 1.4 don't support type parameters which renders them mostly useless at least in my setting where most of things are generic. There is another request in discussion for adding type parameters to aliases: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1616

Hopefully will be enough interest generated for this featrure, so it gets pushed to life.

Comment: Per the comment from @AlekseyBykov — generic type aliases are now live!  See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3397

Comment: I find these type aliases to be useless, since you cannot use them to construct instances. This fails: `type MyMap = Map<string, string>; let map = new MyMap();`

Comment: @jlh Well, type aliases (and types in general) are erased after compilation. So to make it work as you want TS would need to rewrite you `new` call or generate some code for type alias. And this in general is against TS philosophy and [design goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals). You can always create you own `MyMap` class or function that wraps underlying `Map<string, string>;`

Comment: @MariuszPawelski Yes I ended up wrapping it, but it's a pain if the underlying type has a lot of methods you want to use. It would be trivial if it was possible to just extend these types, but that doesn't work either, at least it doesn't for `Map`, there's an open issue for that.

Answer (score 11):

TypeScript supports imports, e.g.:

```
module A {
    export class c {
        d: any;
     }
}

module B {
    import moduleA = A;

    var e: moduleA.c = new moduleA.c();
}

module B2 {
    import Ac = A.c;

    var e: Ac = new Ac();
}
```

#### Update 1

Since TS 1.4 we can use type declarations:

```
type MyHandler = (myArgument: string) => void;

var handler: MyHandler;
```

Since TS 1.6 we can use local type declarations:

```
function f() {
    if (true) {
        interface T { x: number }
        let v: T;
        v.x = 5;
    }
    else {
        interface T { x: string }
        let v: T;
        v.x = "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A poor man's solution is to declare a dummy variable (e.g. `t`) with the desired type and use `typeof t` instead of the long type expression:

```
var t: { (x: number, f: { (foo: string, bar:boolean): void }): void };

var f: typeof t;
var g: typeof t;
```