# Is it possible to define a type that resolves to one of two given types?

Tags: typescript

Assuming I have several functions that return the same `number | Date` type is it possible to define a type that will be one of these two?

I.e. instead of:

```
foo1(): number | Date {}
foo2(): number | Date {}
```

is it possible to have:

```
foo1(): NumberOrDate {}
foo2(): NumberOrDate {}
```

?

Or is there any other idea on how to stay DRY and not repeat `number | Date`?

Comment: `type NumberOrDate = number | Date` should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does TypeScript allow type aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839692/does-typescript-allow-type-aliases)

Comment: @possum the question is not very similar to mine but one of the answers covers my problem indeed so I wouldn't call it a perfect match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#reusable-types-type-aliases) for the union:

```
type NumberOrDate = number | Date

function foo1(): NumberOrDate { return 1;}
function foo2(): NumberOrDate { return new Date}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4HlUBECGxoC8UAdoiqlAD5S74CwAUIwGZzEDGwAlgPbFTMePAIwAKAJQAuWGTSZa0AN5RUEYHFT9hAbgC+LNp179BPAEwTp8ZHOx4lKtRv7EIAdxr3dQA)